# Is a function $f$ integrable iff it satisfies the IVT?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I was having a conversation with another MSE user today and he mentioned that he had heard that "IVT was sufficient for a function to be integrable". When I asked if he meant it was "if-and-only-if" or just "if", he said "if-and-only-if".

This made no sense to me - I imagined a step-function which was 0 for $x<1$ and was 1 for $x\geq1$. This seemed to me to be integrable (with definite integral 1 between 0 and 2) and yet clearly did not satisfy the IVT.

He countered with "step functions are NOT integrable" and further said that he had found the place in the textbook which mentioned this and had verified that it WAS if-and-only-if... Before I could say anything, a movie we wanted to see started.

**Where did I go wrong?**

**I assume he's correct because:
a) He's usually correct and b) I just started calculus and he's been doing it for years.**

However, I thought that my step function was integrable, by the definition of integration that I learnt from Spivak's Calculus a la *lower and upper sums.*

Comment: Step functions are indeed integrable...

Comment: A step-function such as your example even has a classical (Newton) integral.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You have made a very wrong and very misleading statement in your first comment. Please delete that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: step functions don't satisfy the intermediate value property (unless there's only one step…), but they are always integrable. On the other hand, there are differentiable functions $f$ such that $f'$ is not Riemann-integrable. But, since it is a derivative, $f'$ has the intermediate value property (by Darboux's theorem).

Comment: Sorry, step functions are continuous? And they're NOT integrable? (That's also the exact opposite of what I said, but thanks anyway in advance!)

Comment: They are integrable, it is probably just a typo.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is correct now.

Comment: I think you want IVT at the end.

Comment: Thanks José! For a second, I thought that I hadn't understood any analysis! ("First step functions aren't integrable, now they're continuous!")

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would step functions satisfy the IVT with just one step? Surely if at the step, they are "originally" $b$ and then they become $a$ after the step, they never take on the value $\frac{1}{2}(a+b)$?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, of course. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @IskyMathews By step function “with just one step” I meant a constant function.

Comment: That explains it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look at **Darboux's Theorem** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis), It states that every function that results from the differentiation of other functions has the intermediate value property.

We are studying this question: Given an arbitrary function $g$, what properties must $g$ satisfy such that there exists a function $f$ such that $f'$=$g$? (for the entire domain)

Consider $h(x)=-1$ if $x<{0}$ and $h(x)=1$ if $x\ge{0}$. One might be tempted to say that the antiderivative of this function is the absolute value function, however, this is not the case as the absolute value function is *not* differentiable at $x=0$ (however it *is* symmetric differentiable), and certainly the derivative of the absolute value function at $x=0$ is undefined, and not $1$. Note here that $h(x)$ does *not* satisfy the intermediate value property, e.g. there is no point $c$ in the domain such that $h(c)=0$, and this is the precise reason why there fails to be a function $f$ such that $f'=g$.

As usual Isky, likely our misunderstanding has arisen due to communication of a problem rather than the mathematical facts behind it! Perhaps, as I was seeking a function $f$ that was differentiable *everywhere*. On further inspection, I am certain our misunderstanding came about as I was seeking an **antiderivative** whereas you seem to be seeking a **definite integral** - two very different beasts.